# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine django-Angular

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, rest

I am making a web application, back-end with django and front-end with Angular, I am using the django TokenAuthentication for the authentication, when I test the request with POSTMAN or the REST-Framework interface everything works well but when I try to make the POST in Angular I get the next error:

```
 Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 62030)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\eduar\Desktop\zaito\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\eduar\Desktop\zaito\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\eduar\Desktop\zaito\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\eduar\Desktop\zaito\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "c:\users\eduar\anaconda3\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Django-Code:

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class LoginViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        return ObtainAuthToken().post(request)
```

Angular Code:

```
export class LoginService {

  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  baseUrl = environment.Server_url;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(nameUser, passwordUser): Observable <any> {
    const body = {username: nameUser , password: passwordUser};
    for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
      this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/usersActions/login/', body , {headers: this.httpHeaders});
    }
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/usersActions/login/', body , {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: the problem was in angular, I don't why but it happens when use a form, when you usea the form tag and you make the post, django raise that error, use the form of angular instead was the solution